# Aparecen dos ventanas de messagebox.showwarning

Tags: python, tkinter

En primer lugar, hola a todos y gracias por vuestro tiempo. Estoy tratando de realizar un pequeño ejercicio de validación de fechas.

Si la fecha mantiene el formato especificado no hay problema, pero si el formato es erroneo debe aparecer una ventana de aviso de que la fecha es incorrecta.

El caso es que aparece la ventana de aviso, pero al aceptar vuelve a aparecer la misma ventana.`

Gracias a todos por la ayuda.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from datetime import datetime

class Aplicacion(Frame):

    def __init__(self, raiz):

        self.fecha=StringVar()

        super().__init__(raiz, width=300, height=300)
        self.master=raiz 
        self.pack()

        self.fechaEntry = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.fecha, width=10)
        self.fechaEntry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.fechaEntry.focus()
        self.fechaEntry.bind("<FocusOut>", self.valida_fecha)
        self.fechaEntry.bind("<Return>", self.valida_fecha)

    def valida_fecha(self, event):   
    
        try:
            self.date = datetime.strptime(self.fechaEntry.get(), '%d/%m/%Y').strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
            Label(self, text="La fecha es correcta").grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10) 
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showwarning("Error de fecha", "El formato de fecha debe ser 'dd/mm/aaaa'", parent = self)

root = Tk()
app = Aplicacion(root)
app.mainloop()
``
```

Comment: El cuadro de diálogo o `messagebox` solo se ejecuta cuando usted mediante `bind()`, usando el evento de `<FocusOut>` el cual intenta el llamado de la función por lo cual al tener excepción, solo aparece ese cuadro de diálogo al tener ese `bind()`, por tanto, con base en el código mostrado el `messagebox` solo se activa porque usted está usando un evento de foco externo y se muestra al hacer clic en otro control o widget, por lo cual a mi solo me muestra un cuadro de diálogo o `messagebox` solo una vez, puede especificar más el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Si, es correcto.  Al tener dos eventos se generaban dos ventanas, ya que se realiza el evento Return y el evento FocusOut.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara porque se ejecutaban los dos eventos, y recuerda aceptar tu respuesta!